# What is NLTK POS tagger asking me to download?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I just started using a part-of-speech tagger, and I am facing many problems.

I started POS tagging with the following:

```
import nltk
text=nltk.word_tokenize("We are going out.Just you and me.")
```

When I want to print `'text'`, the following happens:

```
print nltk.pos_tag(text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "F:\Python26\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 63, in pos_tag
tagger = nltk.data.load(_POS_TAGGER)
File "F:\Python26\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 594, in load
resource_val = pickle.load(_open(resource_url))
File "F:\Python26\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 673, in _open
 return find(path).open()
 File "F:\Python26\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 455, in find
   raise LookupError(resource_not_found)`  
LookupError:
 Resource 'taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle' not
 found.  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

>>> nltk.download().

 Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
    - 'F:\\Python26\\nltk_data'
    - 'F:\\Python26\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Application Data\\nltk_data'
```

I used `nltk.download()` but it did not work.

Comment: There, I cleaned it up for you. Please take this as an example on how to format future questions.

Comment: thankx...the problem is now solved...

Comment: If you have solved the problem, feel free to post the solution and accept it, so that others with the same problem can find it.

Answer (score 37):

From `NLTK` versions higher than v3.2, please use:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.__version__
'3.2.1'
>>> nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
[nltk_data] Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to
[nltk_data]     /home/alvas/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package averaged_perceptron_tagger is already up-to-date!
True
```

For `NLTK` versions using the old MaxEnt model, i.e. v3.1 and below, please use:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('maxent_treebank_pos_tagger')
[nltk_data] Downloading package maxent_treebank_pos_tagger to
[nltk_data]     /home/alvas/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package maxent_treebank_pos_tagger is already up-to-date!
True
```

For more details on the change in the default `pos_tag`, please see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1143

Answer (score 31):

When you type `nltk.download()` in Python, an NLTK Downloader interface gets displayed automatically.
Click on Models and choose maxent_treebank_pos_. It gets installed automatically.

```
import nltk 
text=nltk.word_tokenize("We are going out.Just you and me.")
print nltk.pos_tag(text)
[('We', 'PRP'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('going', 'VBG'), ('out.Just', 'JJ'),
 ('you', 'PRP'), ('and', 'CC'), ('me', 'PRP'), ('.', '.')]
```

Comment: Even more, you can download it directly in the code if you specify the tagger name `nltk.download('maxent_treebank_pos_tagger');`. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/5208563/62921

Answer (score 5):

From the shell/terminal, you can use:

```
python -m nltk.downloader maxent_treebank_pos_tagger
```

(might need to be sudo on Linux)

It will install `maxent_treebank_pos_tagger` (i.e. the standard treebank POS tagger in NLTK) and fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
import nltk
text = "Obama delivers his first speech."

sent  =  nltk.sent_tokenize(text)


loftags = []
for s in sent:
    d = nltk.word_tokenize(s)   

    print nltk.pos_tag(d)
```

Result :

> akshayy@ubuntu:~/summ$ python nn1.py [('Obama', 'NNP'), ('delivers',
>   'NNS'), ('his', 'PRP$'), ('first', 'JJ'), ('speech', 'NN'), ('.',
>   '.')]

( I just asked another question where used this code )

Comment: It's worth noting that this parse is **incorrect** -- the POS tagger has marked "delivers" as a plural noun...

Answer (score 1):

```
nltk.download()
```

Click on Models and choose maxent_treebank_pos_. It gets installed automatically.

```
import nltk 
text=nltk.word_tokenize("We are going out.Just you and me.")
print nltk.pos_tag(text)
[('We', 'PRP'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('going', 'VBG'), ('out.Just', 'JJ'),
 ('you', 'PRP'), ('and', 'CC'), ('me', 'PRP'), ('.', '.')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If nltk version is 3.4.5, do the below:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
```

To check you nltk version, do the below:

```
print (nltk.__version__)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Google Colab and the current version of NLTK is `3.2.5` as of today.

This is what worked for me.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

text = word_tokenize("Hello welcome to the world of to learn Categorizing and POS Tagging with NLTK and Python")
nltk.pos_tag(text)
```