# error while using nltk.post_tag

Tags: nltk, pos-tagger

I have been trying to use nltk.pos_tag in my code but I face an error when I do so. I have already downloaded Penn treebank and  max_ent_treebank_pos. But the error persists. here is my code :

```
import nltk
from nltk import tag
from nltk import*



a = "Alan Shearer is the first player to score over a hundred Premier League goals."
a_sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(a)
a_words     = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in a_sentences]
a_pos       = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in a_words]
print(a_pos)
```

and this is the error I get :

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
  print (nltk.pos_tag(text))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 110, in  pos_tag
tagger = PerceptronTagger()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\perceptron.py", line 140, in    __init__
AP_MODEL_LOC = 'file:'+str(find('taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/'+PICKLE))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 641, in find
raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError:
```

---

```
 Resource 'taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/averaged_perceptron
 _tagger.pickle' not found.  Please use the NLTK Downloader to
 obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
 Searched in:
   - 'C:\\Users\\T01142/nltk_data'
   - 'C:\\nltk_data'
   - 'D:\\nltk_data'
   - 'E:\\nltk_data'
   - 'C:\\Python34\\nltk_data'
   - 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\nltk_data'
   - 'C:\\Users\\T01142\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do POS tagging using the NLTK POS tagger in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590370/how-to-do-pos-tagging-using-the-nltk-pos-tagger-in-python)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37651321/610569

Comment: Thanks! :) but I got by downloading 'averaged_perceptron_tagger' from nltk downloader

Answer (score 4):

Call this from python:

nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in a Flask server. `nltk` used a different path when in server config, so I recurred to adding `nltk.data.path.append("/home/yourusername/whateverpath/")` inside of the server code right before the `pos_tag` call

Note there is some replication of this question

[How to config nltk data directory from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522372/how-to-config-nltk-data-directory-from-code)

[nltk doesn't add $NLTK_DATA to search path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382937/nltk-doesnt-add-nltk-data-to-search-path/36383314#36383314)

[POS tagging with NLTK. Can't locate averaged_perceptron_tagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174616/pos-tagging-with-nltk-cant-locate-averaged-perceptron-tagger)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error run following command on python prompt:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
```