# Problems in NetworkX pagerank

Tags: python, networkx, pagerank

I'm trying to run NetworkX's pagerank on a really big graph (DiGraph) and I'm always getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "summarize.py", line 120, in <module>
     s = summerizer().summ(q)
  File "summarize.py", line 108, in summ
    rank = nx.pagerank(self.G, 0.9, vector)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/algorithms/link_analysis/pagerank_alg.py",     line 93, in pagerank
    W=nx.stochastic_graph(D, weight=weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/generators/stochastic.py", line 42, in                 stochastic_graph
     d[weight]=d.get(weight,1.0)/degree[u]
 ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I tried removing all nodes with zero degree, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Looking at the code (stochastic_graph() in stochastic.py) I don't see how a divide by zero should ever happen.  Can you reproduce it in a simple case?

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see more of your code. As it is one can speculate on possible causes:

- Page rank works on undirected graphs (see the [docs](http://networkx.lanl.gov/archive/networkx-1.6/_modules/networkx/algorithms/link_analysis/pagerank_alg.html) and this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9247791/1290420). Could the error be caused by pagerank trying to convert edges to two undirected edges?
- Also, does this make a difference?

  rank = nx.pagerank(self.G.to_undirected(), 0.9, vector)